# How to fix my 3 handle shower faucet, husband tried to replace?

Tags: shower

I have a 3 handle shower/tub, the hot water was leaking and my husband tried to fix it but now the hot water turns on the wrong way, the cold water like skips when u turn it on and off and the shower does the same but u cant get it to turn all the way on, water always runs out the bath and when u want to turn just the bath on it barley comes on. What could he of did wrong and could I fix it without having to buy a new kit? If u need anymore information just let me know Ill tell u anything or take pics anything to save me from spending $200 on a plumber that I know I can fix some how.

Comment: Every make and model of "3 handle shower/tub" valves is different. There is absolutely nothing standardized between different manufacturers. Your question implies to me that your husband either: used the wrong replacement valves; rebuilt the existing valves incorrectly; installed the valves incorrectly; or any combination of those things. There is no way we can help you without photos of the old valves and trim/handles (seeing the trim helps with I.D.)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the pics requested above. If you'll take the [tour], it'll give you a hint on how to include pics.

Comment: Your description of the symptoms looks to me as though he's put the innards of the faucet valves back in the incorrect orientation (personal experience :P), and they probably need to be rotated by something like 90 or 180 degrees to get them to operate properly).

Comment: Bad Husband! No Biscuit!